# Umlauts with PHP Soap request

Tags: php, soap

So I have SOAP request something like this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

if ( empty( $id ) )
 die();

$creds = new \stdClass();
$params = new \stdClass();
$client = new SoapClient( 'http://example/source.svc?wsdl', array( 'encoding' => 'UTF-8' ) );
$pwd = 'mypassword';
$creds->Key = "my-special-key";
$params->creds = $creds;
$params->id = $id;
$result = $client->GetData( $params );
$xmlResult = $result-> GetDataResult;
$data = simplexml_load_string( $xmlResult );
// echo it for ajax request
echo json_encode( array(
    $data
) );
```

Now the results has some text in german that umlauts (ä, ö,) and so on. But for example ä shows up Ã¤ when I print the result. Why is that? Is it something to do with simplexml_load_string or my Soap  request?

Answer (score 0):

I think the content header of your response is not UTF-8.

Try

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

before you printout.

Comment: This doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Use php SoapClient for your Soap requests, structure your request like this

```
        $options = array('trace'=> true,'exceptions' => true);            
        $client  = new \SoapClient('https://www.example.com?wsdl',$options);

        $params = new \stdClass();
        $params->yourKeyorIdHere = 'XXXXXX';
        $params->YourKeyOrIDHere = 'XXXXX';
        $soapVar = new \SoapVar($params,SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);

        $header = new \SoapHeader('https://www.example?wsdl','credentials',$soapVar);

        $client->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));


        $result=$client->login(function parameters here);
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't really get the soap request working with this.